# boost::algorithm hex and unhex showing unexpected results

Tags: c++, boost, hex

Edit: looks like I made a dumb mistake :)

Anyone have any idea why the below code results in 2 different hex strings?

There seems to be an extra byte at the beginning. Does boost's hex and unhex not work well together or am I missing something? Better alternatives welcome for C++17!

```
std::string hex(const std::vector<uint8_t>& v)
{
    std::string to;
    boost::algorithm::hex(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(to));
    return to;
}

std::vector<uint8_t> unhex(const std::string& hex)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes = {0};
    boost::algorithm::unhex(hex, std::back_inserter(bytes));
    return bytes;
}

int main() 
{
    string payload = "01630B917123862732F0000002EF18";
    cout << payload << endl;
    cout << hex(unhex(payload)) << endl;
}
```

> Output:
>
> 01630B917123862732F0000002EF18
>
> 0001630B917123862732F0000002EF18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra byte is here:

```
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes = {0};
```

You should remove the extra byte like this:

```
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes;
```

Comment: Ahh. you know what I did. It used to be an array of fixed size and I used {0} to initialize them all to 0's. What a dumb mistake! Thank you!

Comment: Don't beat yourself up. Initialization inconsistencies like these are the bane of C++'s legacy C compatibility. Nobody thinks they're intuitive, and you kinda have to develop a "danger radar" for it. Not a dumb mistake by any stretch.